# Close button is not clickable after expanding menu button in mobile device or small screens

Tags: css

I am using floating menu button from https://www.bootdey.com/snippets/view/Floating-menu
Close button is not clickable after expanding menu button in mobile device or small screen. That is I need to go a litile bit right side to close.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    /* Floating Menu
     **************************************************************/

    var $floatingMenuToggle = $(".floating-menu-toggle-wrap"),
        $floatingMenu = $(".floating-header .main-navigation"),
        $floatingMenuItem = $(".floating-header .main-navigation .menu > li");
    if ($floatingMenu.length) {
        $floatingMenuItem.each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).addClass("delay-" + index);
        });

        $floatingMenuToggle.click(function () {
            var clicks = $(this).data("clicks");
            if (clicks) {
                $floatingMenu.removeClass("is-visible");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $floatingMenuToggle.parent().removeClass("expanded");
                }, 500);
            } else {
                $floatingMenuToggle.parent().addClass("expanded");
                $floatingMenu.addClass("is-visible");
            }
            $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
        });
    }

    // Back Button
    var backBtnText = $floatingMenu.data("back-btn-text"),
        subMenu = $(".floating-header .main-navigation .sub-menu");

    subMenu.each(function () {
        $(this).prepend('<li class="back-btn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + backBtnText + "</a></li>");
    });

    var hasChildLink = $(".floating-header .menu-item-has-children > a"),
        backBtn = $(".floating-header .main-navigation .sub-menu .back-btn");

    backBtn.on("click", function (e) {
        var self = this,
            parent = $(self).parent(),
            siblingParent = $(self).parent().parent().siblings().parent(),
            menu = $(self).parents(".menu");

        parent.removeClass("in-view");
        siblingParent.removeClass("off-view");

        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    hasChildLink.on("click", function (e) {
        var self = this,
            parent = $(self).parent().parent(),
            menu = $(self).parents(".menu");

        parent.addClass("off-view");
        $(self).parent().find("> .sub-menu").addClass("in-view");

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
/******************************************************************/
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #eee;
    height: 1500px;
}
.main-navigation .menu li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
    -o-transition: color 0.3s;
    transition: color 0.3s;
}
.floating-menu-btn {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 70%;
    right: 35px;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle .bar {
    width: 22px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}
.mobile-menu-toggle .bar,
.floating-menu-toggle .bar {
    display: block;
    will-change: transform, opacity;
    width: 32px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 0 0 6px 0;
    background: #333;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.floating-header {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 35px;
}

.floating-header .site-logo {
    max-width: 79px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.floating-header + * {
    padding-top: 190px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .floating-header {
        padding: 25px 15px;
    }
    .floating-header + * {
        padding-top: 175px;
    }
}

.floating-header .main-navigation-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 110;
    display: table;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 110px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.floating-header .main-navigation {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: -110px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(35px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(35px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(35px);
    -o-transform: translateY(35px);
    transform: translateY(35px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.35s 0.2s;
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu.off-view {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu.in-view {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu > li {
    position: static;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu > li > a {
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li {
    display: block;
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li.menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: -100%;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li.menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu > li > a {
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li.menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu.in-view {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li.menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu.off-view {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    -o-animation: none;
    animation: none;
}

.floating-header .main-navigation.is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.ie .floating-header .main-navigation-wrap .main-navigation,
.edge .floating-header .main-navigation-wrap .main-navigation,
.firefox .floating-header .main-navigation-wrap .main-navigation {
    top: 0;
}

.android .floating-header .main-navigation-wrap .main-navigation,
.ios .floating-header .main-navigation-wrap .main-navigation {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s 0s;
    transition: all 0.25s 0s;
}
.floating-menu-btn {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 70%;
    right: 35px;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.floating-menu-btn:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center 30%;
    -moz-transform-origin: center 30%;
    -ms-transform-origin: center 30%;
    transform-origin: center 30%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 28px;
    left: 27px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    right: auto;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}

.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle .bar {
    width: 22px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}

.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle .bar:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.floating-menu-btn.expanded .floating-menu-toggle {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.floating-menu-btn.expanded .floating-menu-toggle .bar:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-9px, 3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -moz-transform: translate(-9px, 3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -ms-transform: translate(-9px, 3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -o-transform: translate(-9px, 3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    transform: translate(-9px, 3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
}

.floating-menu-btn.expanded .floating-menu-toggle .bar:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-9px, -3px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -moz-transform: translate(-9px, -3px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -ms-transform: translate(-9px, -3px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -o-transform: translate(-9px, -3px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    transform: translate(-9px, -3px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
}

.floating-menu-btn.expanded:before {
    -webkit-transform: scale(80);
    -moz-transform: scale(80);
    -ms-transform: scale(80);
    -o-transform: scale(80);
    transform: scale(80);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .floating-menu-btn {
        right: 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="floating-header">
    <a href="#" class="site-logo" style="font-size: 30px; color: #5bc0de; font-weight: bold;">
        Bootdey.com
    </a>

    <div class="floating-menu-btn">
        <div class="floating-menu-toggle-wrap">
            <div class="floating-menu-toggle">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-navigation-wrap">
        <nav class="main-navigation" data-back-btn-text="Back">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item-has-children current-menu-item delay-0">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>More Options</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home Design Agency</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home Architecture</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home Photographer</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="delay-1"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="delay-2"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="delay-3"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="delay-4"><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                <li class="delay-5"><a href="#">Elements</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- .menu -->
        </nav>
        <!-- .main-navigation -->
    </div>
    <!-- .main-navigation-wrap -->
</header>
```

My site is https://monsoonmalabar.com/sonyshop/

Please note I changed `.floating-menu-btn{ top: 70%;}` from original.

Comment: Any help here ...?

Comment: Hello, anyone here to hrlp?

Comment: Looks like working in the snippet you posted.

Comment: @Dakshank check in very small screen

Answer (score 0):

Here's fix for the issue. Snippet you provided has the issue itself.
You can find and replace these CSS in your code

```
.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle-wrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
/* Floating Menu
    **************************************************************/

    var $floatingMenuToggle = $('.floating-menu-toggle-wrap'),
            $floatingMenu = $('.floating-header .main-navigation'),
            $floatingMenuItem = $('.floating-header .main-navigation .menu > li');
    if($floatingMenu.length) {
        $floatingMenuItem.each(function(index, element) {
            $(element).addClass('delay-' + index);
        });

        $floatingMenuToggle.click(function() {
          var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
          if (clicks) {
                $floatingMenu.removeClass('is-visible');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $floatingMenuToggle.parent().removeClass('expanded');
                }, 500);
          } else {
                $floatingMenuToggle.parent().addClass('expanded');
                $floatingMenu.addClass('is-visible');
          }
          $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
        });

    }

    // Back Button
    var backBtnText = $floatingMenu.data( 'back-btn-text' ),
            subMenu = $( '.floating-header .main-navigation .sub-menu' );

    subMenu.each( function () {
        $( this ).prepend( '<li class="back-btn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + backBtnText + '</a></li>' );
    } );

    var hasChildLink = $( '.floating-header .menu-item-has-children > a' ),
        backBtn = $( '.floating-header .main-navigation .sub-menu .back-btn' );

    backBtn.on('click', function (e) {
        var self = this,
            parent = $( self ).parent(),
            siblingParent = $( self ).parent().parent().siblings().parent(),
            menu = $( self ).parents( '.menu' );

        parent.removeClass( 'in-view' );
        siblingParent.removeClass( 'off-view' );

        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    hasChildLink.on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        var self = this,
            parent = $( self ).parent().parent(),
            menu = $( self ).parents( '.menu' );

        parent.addClass( 'off-view' );
        $( self ).parent().find( '> .sub-menu' ).addClass( 'in-view' );

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } );
    } );
    /******************************************************************/
```

```css
body{
    margin-top:20px;
    background:#eee;
    height:1500px;
}
.main-navigation .menu li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
    -o-transition: color 0.3s;
    transition: color 0.3s;
}
.floating-menu-btn {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 50px;
    right: 35px;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle .bar {
    width: 22px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}
.mobile-menu-toggle .bar, .floating-menu-toggle .bar {
    display: block;
    will-change: transform, opacity;
    width: 32px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 0 0 6px 0;
    background: #333;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.floating-header {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 35px
}

.floating-header .site-logo {
    max-width: 79px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 !important
}

.floating-header+* {
    padding-top: 190px
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .floating-header {
        padding: 25px 15px
    }
    .floating-header+* {
        padding-top: 175px
    }
}

.floating-header .main-navigation-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 110;
    display: table;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 110px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden
}

.floating-header .main-navigation {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: -110px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(35px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(35px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(35px);
    -o-transform: translateY(35px);
    transform: translateY(35px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.35s 0.2s
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1)
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu.off-view {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu.in-view {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu>li {
    position: static;
    border-bottom: none
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu>li>a {
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li {
    display: block
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li.menu-item-has-children>.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: -100%;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1)
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li.menu-item-has-children>.sub-menu>li>a {
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li.menu-item-has-children>.sub-menu.in-view {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li.menu-item-has-children>.sub-menu.off-view {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)
}

.floating-header .main-navigation .menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    -o-animation: none;
    animation: none
}

.floating-header .main-navigation.is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
}

.ie .floating-header .main-navigation-wrap .main-navigation,
.edge .floating-header .main-navigation-wrap .main-navigation,
.firefox .floating-header .main-navigation-wrap .main-navigation {
    top: 0
}

.android .floating-header .main-navigation-wrap .main-navigation,
.ios .floating-header .main-navigation-wrap .main-navigation {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s 0s;
    transition: all 0.25s 0s
}
.floating-menu-btn {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: initial;
    bottom: 80px;
    right: 35px;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center 30%;
    -moz-transform-origin: center 30%;
    -ms-transform-origin: center 30%;
    transform-origin: center 30%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)
}

.floating-menu-btn:hover{
background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle-wrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
}

.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle .bar {
    width: 22px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0
}

.floating-menu-btn .floating-menu-toggle .bar:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.floating-menu-btn.expanded .floating-menu-toggle {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg)
}

.floating-menu-btn.expanded .floating-menu-toggle .bar:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-9px, 3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -moz-transform: translate(-9px, 3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -ms-transform: translate(-9px, 3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -o-transform: translate(-9px, 3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    transform: translate(-9px, 3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1)
}

.floating-menu-btn.expanded .floating-menu-toggle .bar:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-9px, -3px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -moz-transform: translate(-9px, -3px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -ms-transform: translate(-9px, -3px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    -o-transform: translate(-9px, -3px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
    transform: translate(-9px, -3px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1)
}

.floating-menu-btn.expanded:before {
    -webkit-transform: scale(80);
    -moz-transform: scale(80);
    -ms-transform: scale(80);
    -o-transform: scale(80);
    transform: scale(80)
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .floating-menu-btn {
        right: 15px
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<header class="floating-header">
  <a href="#" class="site-logo" style="font-size:30px;color:#5bc0de;font-weight:bold">
    Bootdey.com
  </a>

  <div class="floating-menu-btn">
    <div class="floating-menu-toggle-wrap">
      <div class="floating-menu-toggle">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-navigation-wrap">
    <nav class="main-navigation" data-back-btn-text="Back">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item-has-children current-menu-item delay-0">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>More Options</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home Design Agency</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home Architecture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home Photographer</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="delay-1"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="delay-2"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="delay-3"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="delay-4"><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        <li class="delay-5"><a href="#">Elements</a></li>
      </ul><!-- .menu -->
    </nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
  </div><!-- .main-navigation-wrap -->
</header>
```

Comment: still not working in small screen. You can drag the developer tool elements to left to decrease width to make it very small screen and test.

Comment: can please check the above snippet? is it having the same issue?

Comment: Not working .....

Comment: when you check in small screen, you get it working?

Comment: I have added hover effect to the button. check now.

Comment: I think you got your fix.

Comment: https://mega.nz/file/T2ZT0Zab#a7UJYSjIdnLbJeSB9ZJBzdcNEZqQ6FmNnaDT90hPCqU
In this video you can see that I can close menu only when I go right side of button

Comment: please look into it

Comment: Look into it please

Comment: hi I am sure by updating your code with above snippet code will fix the issue.
I hope you know the coding part.